# "poetry version" command is duplicating code in pyproject.toml

Tags: python-poetry

I'm using `poetry version minor` to increment the version of my package. I thought that was all it did, but it's modifying the rest of my pyproject.toml

Specifically it's

- moving build-system within the file
- duplicating 2 sets of tool.poetry.plugins

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why ask this question on StackOverflow? I'd recommend asking this on [poetry's github discussions group](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/discussions). -- Anyway, what poetry version are you using? Seeing how you claim to have a `[tool.poetry.plugins]`, which does not officially exist as far as I know, I am wondering if maybe you are using unstable code...

Comment: Hi @sinoroc thanks for the help. the plugins look like it's documented here: https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#plugins. I didn't create the file so I'm not super familiar with poetry, but I'll put this question on the discussion site. We're using poetry 1.0.10. Thanks for the direction to the discussion. I'll try that too

Comment: Ah my bad, of course the `[tool.poetry.plugins]` section is official. I had something else in mind, you're absolutely right. -- Back to the issue: it might be a bug in _poetry_, so I think it should be discussed on poetry's GitHub rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: Cool. Moving some stuff around fixed it and I opened the discussion on github. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The fix** was to move the [build-system] into the location in the pyproject it was being auto-moved to and then the duplication stopped.

Why this fixed it is still a mystery. If someone wants to elaborate why this is the case I'll mark that as the answer, otherwise I'll close this.

Here's a very limited [github discussion](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/discussions/3554#discussioncomment-269676)